# thunderbird bug accessing to tab with messenger.messageDisplay.getDisplayedMessage

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, thunderbird-webextensions

I am trying to access the content of a tab. But most of the time it gives an error. Has the code ever worked?

list of tabs:

```js
messenger.tabs.query(
  {
    active: false ,
    currentWindow: true
  }
).then( (tabs) => { console.log (tabs); })
```

then:

```
messenger.messageDisplay.getDisplayedMessage(4).then ((msn) => {
 console.log(msn);
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9VpC.png)
but 99% msn is null.

Please see the attach files

thanks!!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvadQ.png)

Comment: well... i am learning... the tabs must be displayed.... but ... how can change the tab focus for displayed another tab???  thanks

Comment: There seems to be a `browser.tabs.update()` function, taking an `updateProperties` with an `active` flag as an argument. Did you try that? See [documentation](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/78/tabs.html#update-tabid-updateproperties).